# What is a suitable method to create a Laravel project in /var/www/html directory?

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, apache2, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint and I have installed apache2 and composer, I have installed the Laravel Installer as a global Composer dependency using this command: `composer global require "laravel/installer"` later I created a project somewhere in home directory and ran `php artisan serve`, my question is if I want to create a project in /var/www/html directory, should I use this command `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app` or `laravel new example-app`?

Comment: They do the same thing under the hood so flip a coin.

Answer (score 0):

both do the same job for you.
Laravel CLI is just a wrapper around the composer command to be more user-friendly.

besides this. I would suggest you move the project whenever you want to serve the application with the Nginx webserver. for the local development, the `php artisan serve` command and the [Laravel homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead) do the job easier.

Comment: what if I want to use Apache as the web server? does it make any difference?